# How can I get 'hg pull' to honor trusted-users section in my .hgrc?

Tags: mercurial, hgrc

I'm sharing a Mercurial repo with a user `dias`, whom I would trust with my life as well as my data.  I therefore added

```
[trusted]
users = dias, nr
```

to my `~/.hgrc` file.  However, when I pull from a remote repo with `hg pull -v`, I always get this message:

```
remote: Not trusting file /r/c--/papers/gentileset-popl2010/.hg/hgrc from untrusted user dias, group c--
remote: Not trusting file /r/c--/papers/gentileset-popl2010/.hg/hgrc from untrusted user dias, group c--
```

(I don't know why the message appears twice.)

**How to I explain to Mercurial that I really want to trust this file?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's on the remote machine that the trust isn't established, and your local .hgrc only affects users on the local machine.  Put the trust section line in your remote .hgrc (in your homedir on the machine where the remote repository lives).  That, of course, assumes you're using 'ssh://' remote URLs.  If you're using 'http://' URLs to access the repository then it's the .hgrc of the apache (or wwwuser or whatever) user on the remote machine that needs to assert trust.